# Why Am I getting a zero instead?

Tags: c++, math, format, zero

I'm a bit new to C++ and I'm making this small program to calculate the gross total of movies tickets.

```
#include<iostream>
#include<string>
#include<iomanip>
#include<cmath>

using namespace std;

int adultTick, childTick;
const int aPrice = 14;
const int cPrice = 10;
float rate() {
    const double RATE = .20;
    return RATE;
}

double grossTotal = (aPrice * adultTick) + (cPrice * childTick);
int main() {

    cout << "Box Office Earnings Calculator ....\n" << endl;
    cout << "Please Enter the Name of the Movie: ";
    string movie_name;

    getline(cin, movie_name);


    cout << endl << "   \"   \"   " << "adult tickets sold: ";
    cin >> adultTick;

    cout << "   \"   \"   " << "child tickets sold: ";
    cin >> childTick;

    cout << endl << setw(10) << left << "Movie Title: " << setw(20) << right << " \" " << movie_name << " \" " << endl;
    cout << setw(10) << left << "Adult Tickets Sold: " << setw(20) << right << adultTick << endl;
    cout << setw(10) << left << "Child Tickets Sold: " << setw(20) << right << childTick << endl;
    cout << setw(10) << left << "Gross Box Office Profit: " << setw(20) << right << "$ " << grossTotal;


}
```

At the very end, there is where the program its suppose to display the total? I thought the Arithmetic was correct however I don't understand Why it continuously displays a zero? What could I be doing wrong?
It works if I don't create a variable for the Arithmetic "grossTotal" but I have to do further formatting with "setprecision" and "fixed" function.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The code in `main` doesn't change `grossTotal`.

The declaration

```
double grossTotal = (aPrice * adultTick) + (cPrice * childTick);
```

… creates a variable `grossTotal` with a specified initial value. It does not declare a relationship between the values of these variables.

At the time the initializer expression (to the right of `=`) is evaluated `adultTick` and `childTick` are zero, because as namespace scope variables they have been zero-initialized.

Comment: Not sure, but the main point is that the declaration does not specify a relationship, it only specifies an initial value.

Answer (score 1):

```
int adultTick, childTick;
```

The shown code declares these variables in the global scope, and these variables get zero-initialized.

```
double grossTotal = (aPrice * adultTick) + (cPrice * childTick);
```

The shown code also declares this variable in the global scope, and the calculated formula computes to 0, so this variable will be set to 0.

```
cout << setw(10) << left << "Gross Box Office Profit: " << setw(20) << right << "$ " << grossTotal;
```

And this line in `main()` displays the value of the `grossTotal` variable, which is, of course, 0.

It is true that before this line, the preceding code in `main()` sets `adultTick` and `childTick`. Which makes no difference whatsoever, since the value of `grossTotal` has been initialized, already.

You need to change your code so that `main()` calculates the value of `grossTotal`, after these other variables are set.